# In a UML2 state diagram what shows just arrived from a history pseudostate?

Tags: event-handling, uml, state

I would like to transition from a state if I have just arrived in that state from a history pseudostate. How do I show the event?

Currently I have an event titled: **just arrived from history** but this feels a bit clunky.

Comment: So you want to trigger a transition from a state S to another state S2 if you arrived on S from a history pseudostate "H", right!? So whty do you need to go through this state S and you do not directly from H to S2 !?

Comment: Because the point of the history pseudo state is that I may be returning to any one of a number of states. I only want to transition to S2 if I came from S. Yes, I want to go straight to S2 if I originated in S but how do I show that?